# Visualizing iris dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, chart.js

```
    @RequestMapping("/analytics/iris2")
public String getAvgPetalbySpecies2(Model model) {
    ArrayList<RTestVO> irisList = analyticsService.getAvgPetalBySpecies2();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String irisData = gson.toJson(irisList);
    model.addAttribute("irisData", irisData);

    return "analytics/chart";

}
```

---

this is my Controller. so, I want to visualizing graph in 
'localhost:8080/destiny/analytics/visual'. 
and I made my visual.jsp.

---

```
    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js">
</script>

 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    <!-- x axis -->
    labels: ["setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'iris species',
        data: [12, 19, 3],  <!-- sample number... I dont want them -->


        <!-- bg -->
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
        ],
        <!-- border -->
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'

        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},

options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
</script>
```

---

this is my visual.jsp and I made for chart.js code.
I want use "request.getAttribute("irisData")" in visual.jsp.

My final question is where I insert my request.getAttribute("irisData") in chart.js script...

Comment: Oh, I pixed my opinion
("/analytics/iris2") --> ("/analytics/visual")
return "analytics/chart"; --> return "analytics/visual"

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you need Spring controller added attribute `model.addAttribute("irisData", irisData);` in your javascript code.

You can try this

In your javascript code

```
<script>
    ...

    var irisData= <c:out value="${irisData}"/> // You can now use irisData in your Chartjs code.

    ...

</script>
```

Comment: Did this help ?

Comment: Thanks for your help!
but, i didn't execute final process... iris data showing web page well... but it didn't work visualizing... and I find 2 destination

Comment: First solution is changing highchart, second solution is using R graph direct showing web-page...
Anyway I appreciate your help!